# Javascript: Clicking thumbnails to switch a larger image. Best method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, gallery

I've been looking for a really easy/lightweight way to just be able to click thumbnails to switch the src of a larger image.

- This is what I've found:
  http://snipplr.com/view/8688/jquery-image-swap/

I haven't actually tried it out yet. Is this the best solution?

The larger images to be swapped in will have the same width but a different height. Will this cause problems/is there something I need to add for this functionality? Would it be better to do a div with a background-image that swaps and is the height of the largest image?

Also, someone said that it only works once (??)... I'd need it to start out on a certain image, then be able to change to 2-4 other images on thumbnail click.

Thanks for any advice! I'm certainly (obviously) no Javascript writer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to switch images as many times as you wish.

The piece of code you reference replaces the image source of #target, with the href of a link within a #thumbs div.  It should work fine.

```
<img id="target" src="images/main.jpg">

<div id="thumbs">
<a href="images/picture1_big.jpg"><img src="images/picture1_small.jpg"></a>
<a href="images/picture2_big.jpg"><img src="images/picture2_small.jpg"></a>
<a href="images/picture3_big.jpg"><img src="images/picture3_small.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Now as far as width and height, I am pretty sure there are some cross-browser compatibility issues with how browsers handle a defined width, but an undefined height, when you swap out the images.

In firefox, the following works.  Plain old javascript, no jquery:

```
<html>

   <head>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         function swap(image) {
             document.getElementById("main").src = image.href;
         }
     </script>

   </head>

   <body>

     <img id="main" src="images/main.jpg" width="50">

     <a href="images/picture1_big.jpg" onclick="swap(this); return false;"><img src="images/picture1_small.jpg"></a>
     <a href="images/picture2_big.jpg" onclick="swap(this); return false;"><img src="images/picture2_small.jpg"></a>
     <a href="images/picture3_big.jpg" onclick="swap(this); return false;"><img src="images/picture3_small.jpg"></a>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For the undefined height issue, do you think my idea about using a div background-image swap instead would work better? Thank you for the answer! Also, the jQuery doesn't require any "inline" javascript, correct? So that would be its advantage?

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to modify the first code to switch a div background-image instead? Would I change the class of the containing div or could I change the background-image directly somehow?

Comment: Since jQuery is just repackaged javascript, it essentially does the same thing, except that it is assigning the "onclicks" in the code.  I.e. $("#thumbs a").click( function() ...  assigns click methods to each 'a' tag in the #thumbs div.  You can do this with plain javascript too, by using a getElementById and a getElementByTagName and then iterating though the results and then adding event listeners.

Comment: To change a background image, you would change the line in the function to read:
document.getElementById("main").class.backgroundImage = 'url('+image.href+')';
This assumes that main is a div and not an img.

Answer (score 2):

This example eliminates loading time after clicking on thumbnails:

HTML:

```
<div id="big-image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/fashion/1/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/1/">
</div>

<div class="small-images">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#big-image img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
    $(".small-images img").click(function(e){
        var index = $(this).index();
        $("#big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/2/

Answer (score 0):

there is also another solution too :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <img id="image" src="" alt="" />
    <script>
      const thumbnailUrl = "./thumbnail.jpeg";
      const wideImageUrl = "./wide-image.jpeg";

      const image = document.getElementById("image");
      image.src = thumbnailUrl;
      let isThumbnail = true;

      image.addEventListener("click", () => {
        image.src = isThumbnail ? wideImageUrl : thumbnailUrl;
        isThumbnail = !isThumbnail;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```