# How to make a simple pure css or jquery image toggle?

Tags: css, onclick, toggle

I surprisingly have not been able to find a simple solution & am fairly new with jquery. I would prefer to use pure css but am open for a simple jquery solution.

I want to have a large image. Below the large image there are a few small images including a small version of the large image. When any one of the small thumbnails is clicked, it becomes the large image.

```
<div class="large-image-wrapper">
    <img src="/link/to/image1" class="large-image"/>
    <img src="/link/to/image2" class="large-image"/>
    <img src="/link/to/image3" class="large-image"/>
</div>

<div class="small-image-wrapper">
    <img src="/link/to/small-image1/" class="small-image"/>
    <img src="/link/to/small-image2/" class="small-image"/>
    <img src="/link/to/small-image3/" class="small-image"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this thread that may help you out:
[Javascript: Clicking thumbnails to switch a larger image. Best method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640727/javascript-clicking-thumbnails-to-switch-a-larger-image-best-method)

-- and there's a jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/2/

```
$(function(){
    $(".large-image-wrapper img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
    $(".small-image-wrapper img").click(function(e){
        var index = $(this).index();
        $(".large-image-wrapper img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: That jsfiddle doesn't make sense.  It works on their js fiddle but I don't see a class of big images in the html as stated in their css. .small-images a, .big-images a {display:inline-block}. Not sure how it's working.  There is an ID of big image ( no s on the end as well )

Comment: The CSS that's in there isn't being applied to anything (it's looking for "a" tags, but there are none) - I posted it because the jQuery is what you're looking for in your example. You'd replace it with your own IDs and classes - like so: http://jsfiddle.net/3jzn7yuu/

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I think there is a deeper problem with my jquery not working. You can see how I've re-created that jsfiddle here. http://www.firebraindesign.com/LRG/rim-toggle/

Comment: It's not working because you grabbed the divs from the first jsfiddle and the jQuery from the second one. The IDs and classes they have ("small-images" and "big-image") don't align with the classes you gave your divs in your question ("large-image-wrapper" and "small-image-wrapper"); therefore, your jQuery doesn't know what to apply the action to - it's looking for classes in your HTML that do not exist.

Comment: that's embarrassing. Good call. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. I'd be lying if I said I've never done it myself. :)