# Image-swap script won't swap images

Tags: javascript

I’m having a very rough time getting the image switch mechanism from this link, [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640727/javascript-clicking-thumbnails-to-switch-a-larger-image-best-method)     , to function. It’s exactly what I need. please help, fellows. I’ve thoroughly checked my image relations and switched the locations of scripts around.

```
<div id="big-image">
    <img id="main" src="images/goldenkoa_huge.png" width="400" height="400" alt="Canadian Maple, Engineered Luxury Click Vinyl Plank flooring"><br />

<a href="images/GoldenKoa-208x166_NEW3_big.gif" onclick="swap(this); return false;"><img src="images/GoldenKoa-208x166_NEW3.gif"></a>
<a href="images/picture2_big.jpg" onclick="swap(this); return false;"><img src="images/picture2_small.jpg"></a>
<a href="images/picture3_big.jpg" onclick="swap(this); return false;"><img src="images/picture3_small.jpg"></a>
```

I have the following scripts loaded at the end of my head (I’ve also tried to move scripts to above body closing tag) :

```
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
         function swap(image) {
             document.getElementById("main").src = image.href;
         }
     </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure any of the image paths you are setting are valid paths, or the script you are inserting is valid and is not breaking your javascript.

Here is a working example:

```js
function swap(image) {
             document.getElementById("main").src = image.href;
         }
```

```html
<div id="big-image">
    <img id="main" src="images/goldenkoa_huge.png" width="400" height="400" alt="Canadian Maple, Engineered Luxury Click Vinyl Plank flooring"><br />


<a href="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQV0TizaFIS4djTY-YgucL1dHDNseSPN9Ib74LVY40R1zYja6AV" onclick="swap(this); return false;"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQV0TizaFIS4djTY-YgucL1dHDNseSPN9Ib74LVY40R1zYja6AV" height="50px"></a>

<a href="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRqQOQHwPkBuYIcoUI4MpbDdbz0WUM2ql5l2HQ9keK-urytm8Vdgg" onclick="swap(this); return false;"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRqQOQHwPkBuYIcoUI4MpbDdbz0WUM2ql5l2HQ9keK-urytm8Vdgg" height="50px"></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need. using the above html and pacing the above function into my script, either below css links or above body closing tag, yields no results. I've also tried

Comment: running the script with no other scripts, including with/without jQuery. I'm seeing all three images... but no swap.